# Pandas dataframe first value shows up as column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas, I have a pandas data frame, but the first value (0,0), is being used as an index/name? I want 0.9121 to be the first value, how do I do that?

```
0    0.2171
1    0.21163
2    0.87221
3    0.432735
4    0.3231
Name: 0.9121, dtype: float64
```

I would like to have:

```
0    0.9121
1    0.2171
2    0.21163
3    0.87221
4    0.432735
5    0.3231
```

Comment: Use `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)` if created DataFrame from file

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same problem, I was already saving it with ```header=False```

Comment: You can also use names=['col_name'] and see what happens. Also restart kernel in jupyter because jezrael's solution should work

Comment: If save file by `header=False` then get default columns names (`0,1,2`) if use `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)`